# Bootstrap fixed navbar & anchors being hidden

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having problems with a bootstrap site I am making, where anchors to content are being hidden underneath the top navbar when clicked. I have read about other people having this issue, and have spent hours trying to create a solution of my own and those of accepted answers for other peoples sites.

Here is example of the site I uploaded which shows the problem when clicking the hyperlink glyphicons: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qzf2v3ce/)

I have tried the

```
padding-top:70px; margin-top:-70px;
```

fix on the entries class, which just messes up the layout, and all possible variations of margins and padding I can think of, which at best gave me the effect I wanted but ended up making the boxes 70 pixels taller at the top only, which I don't want, I want everything the size it is but the anchors to not be scrolled under the navbar when clicked

I also tried making a javascript/jquery fix to automatically scroll down 70 pixels when a click on the correctly formatted anchor was detected, which worked slightly, I even got it to work when loading the page via a url and not a mouseclick (site.com/#div), however I had issues when reloading the page via a refresh that I didn't know how to fix; I'd really like to solve this via CSS because it seems like there should be a way to do it without having to rely on someone having JS enabled

Edit: [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h8Kd.png) of what happens when you click an anchor (left) and what I want to happen (right)

Comment: can you explain the question more clear ?

Comment: @Naila When a glyphicon link (the blue link icons in the bottom right of each box in this example) is clicked, it scrolls such that the top of the div linked to is hidden under the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this code , Anchor tag has default behavior when we click on it it will go to top of the page , if we want to remove that we need to use jQuery `preventDefault()`

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
.hoverlist :hover {
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.name h3 {
 text-align: center
}
body {
 margin-top: 70px;
}
.entries {
}
</style>
  <script>
   $(function(){
  $('.date').on('click','a',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    var section = this.href;
    var sectionClean = section.substring(section.indexOf("#"));
    $("html, body").animate({
   scrollTop: $(sectionClean).offset().top - 70
    }, 1000, function () {
   //window.location.hash = sectionClean;
    });
  });
 });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Sitename</a> </div>
  </nav>
  
<div class="container">
<ul class="list-group hoverlist">
    <li id="1" class="list-group-item entries">
    <div class="name">
        <h3>jfklsdfjasklsjdlkasdjflkasfjkl</h3>
      </div>
    <div class="ids">
        <h4>fhdsjkafhsdkjfsdf</h4>
        f23f2f, <a href="#">hjsdfkhfjksdfsdklfkaf</a>, fdjsklfsd</div>
    <div class="reason">
        <h4>fasdjkfasf</h4>
        fsdjklasdjl;fkfjalkfdjfkadfjajsdkfjsalksjadlfksadjlksdfsdffasfsaf</div>
    <div class="date">
        <h4>sdfasdfsf</h4>
        fasdfsf<a href="#1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link pull-right"></span></a></div>
  </li>
    <li id="2" class="list-group-item entries">
    <div class="name">
        <h3>jfklsdfjasklsjdlkasdjflkasfjkl</h3>
      </div>
    <div class="ids">
        <h4>fhdsjkafhsdkjfsdf</h4>
        fjasdklfjasdkfasd, jfkdl239fj23f2f, <a href="#">hjsdfkhfjksdfsdklfkaf</a>, fdjsklfsd</div>
    <div class="reason">
        <h4>fasdjkfasf</h4>
        fsdjklasdjl;fkfjalkfdjfkadfjajsdkfjsalksjadlfksadjlksdjkasdjsdkffjdslakfsdfasdfasdsadfsdffasfsaf</div>
    <div class="date">
        <h4>sdfasdfsf</h4>
        fasdfsf<a href="#2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link pull-right"></span></a></div>
  </li>
    <li id="3" class="list-group-item entries">
    <div class="name">
        <h3>jfklsdfjasklsjdlkasdjflkasfjkl</h3>
      </div>
    <div class="ids">
        <h4>fhdsjkafhsdkjfsdf</h4>
        fjasdklfjasdkfasd, jfkdl239fj23f2f, <a href="#">hjsdfkhfjksdfsdklfkaf</a>, fdjsklfsd</div>
    <div class="reason">
        <h4>fasdjkfasf</h4>
        fsdjklasdjl;fkfjalkfdjfkadfjajsdkfjsalksjadlfksadjlksdjkasdjsdkffjdslakfsdfasdfasdsadfsdffasfsaf</div>
    <div class="date">
        <h4>sdfasdfsf</h4>
        fasdfsf<a href="#3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link pull-right"></span></a></div>
  </li>
    <li id="4" class="list-group-item entries">
    <div class="name">
        <h3>jfklsdfjasklsjdlkasdjflkasfjkl</h3>
      </div>
    <div class="ids">
        <h4>fhdsjkafhsdkjfsdf</h4>
        fjasdklfjasdkfasd, jfkdl239fj23f2f, <a href="#">hjsdfkhfjksdfsdklfkaf</a>, fdjsklfsd</div>
    <div class="reason">
        <h4>fasdjkfasf</h4>
        fsdjklasdjl;fkfjalkfdjfkadfjajsdkfjsalksjadlfksadjlksdjkasdjsdkffjdslakfsdfasdfasdsadfsdffasfsaf</div>
    <div class="date">
        <h4>sdfasdfsf</h4>
        fasdfsf<a href="#4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link pull-right"></span></a></div>
  </li>
    <li id="5" class="list-group-item entries">
    <div class="name">
        <h3>jfklsdfjasklsjdlkasdjflkasfjkl</h3>
      </div>
    <div class="ids">
        <h4>fhdsjkafhsdkjfsdf</h4>
        fjasdklfjasdkfasd, jfkdl239fj23f2f, <a href="#">hjsdfkhfjksdfsdklfkaf</a>, fdjsklfsd</div>
    <div class="reason">
        <h4>fasdjkfasf</h4>
        fsdjklasdjl;fkfjalkfdjfkadfjajsdkfjsalksjadlfksadjlksdjkasdjsdkffjdslakfsdfasdfasdsadfsdffasfsaf</div>
    <div class="date">
        <h4>sdfasdfsf</h4>
        fasdfsf<a href="#5"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link pull-right"></span></a></div>
  </li>
    <li id="6" class="list-group-item entries">
    <div class="name">
        <h3>jfklsdfjasklsjdlkasdjflkasfjkl</h3>
      </div>
    <div class="ids">
        <h4>fhdsjkafhsdkjfsdf</h4>
        fjasdklfjasdkfasd, jfkdl239fj23f2f, <a href="#">hjsdfkhfjksdfsdklfkaf</a>, fdjsklfsd</div>
    <div class="reason">
        <h4>fasdjkfasf</h4>
        fsdjklasdjl;fkfjalkfdjfkadfjajsdkfjsalksjadlfksadjlksdjkasdjsdkffjdslakfsdfasdfasdsadfsdffasfsaf</div>
    <div class="date">
        <h4>sdfasdfsf</h4>
        fasdfsf<a href="#6"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link pull-right"></span></a></div>
  </li>
    <li id="7" class="list-group-item entries">
    <div class="name">
        <h3>jfklsdfjasklsjdlkasdjflkasfjkl</h3>
      </div>
    <div class="ids">
        <h4>fhdsjkafhsdkjfsdf</h4>
        fjasdklfjasdkfasd, jfkdl239fj23f2f, <a href="#">hjsdfkhfjksdfsdklfkaf</a>, fdjsklfsd</div>
    <div class="reason">
        <h4>fasdjkfasf</h4>
        fsdjklasdjl;fkfjalkfdjfkadfjajsdkfjsalksjadlfksadjlksdjkasdjsdkffjdslakfsdfasdfasdsadfsdffasfsaf</div>
    <div class="date">
        <h4>sdfasdfsf</h4>
        fasdfsf<a href="#7"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link pull-right"></span></a></div>
  </li>
    <li id="8" class="list-group-item entries">
    <div class="name">
        <h3>jfklsdfjasklsjdlkasdjflkasfjkl</h3>
      </div>
    <div class="ids">
        <h4>fhdsjkafhsdkjfsdf</h4>
        fjasdklfjasdkfasd, jfkdl239fj23f2f, <a href="#">hjsdfkhfjksdfsdklfkaf</a>, fdjsklfsd</div>
    <div class="reason">
        <h4>fasdjkfasf</h4>
        fsdjklasdjl;fkfjalkfdjfkadfjajsdkfjsalksjadlfksadjlksdjkasdjsdkffjdslakfsdfasdfasdsadfsdffasfsaf</div>
    <div class="date">
        <h4>sdfasdfsf</h4>
        fasdfsf<a href="#8"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link pull-right"></span></a></div>
  </li>
    <li id="9" class="list-group-item entries">
    <div class="name">
        <h3>jfklsdfjasklsjdlkasdjflkasfjkl</h3>
      </div>
    <div class="ids">
        <h4>fhdsjkafhsdkjfsdf</h4>
        fjasdklfjasdkfasd, jfkdl239fj23f2f, <a href="#">hjsdfkhfjksdfsdklfkaf</a>, fdjsklfsd</div>
    <div class="reason">
        <h4>fasdjkfasf</h4>
        fsdjklasdjl;fkfjalkfdjfkadfjajsdkfjsalksjadlfksadjlksdjkasdjsdkffjdslakfsdfasdfasdsadfsdffasfsaf</div>
    <div class="date">
        <h4>sdfasdfsf</h4>
        fasdfsf<a href="#9"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link pull-right"></span></a></div>
  </li>
    <li id="10" class="list-group-item entries">
    <div class="name">
        <h3>jfklsdfjasklsjdlkasdjflkasfjkl</h3>
      </div>
    <div class="ids">
        <h4>fhdsjkafhsdkjfsdf</h4>
        fjasdklfjasdkfasd, jfkdl239fj23f2f, <a href="#">hjsdfkhfjksdfsdklfkaf</a>, fdjsklfsd</div>
    <div class="reason">
        <h4>fasdjkfasf</h4>
        fsdjklasdjl;fkfjalkfdjfkadfjajsdkfjsalksjadlfksadjlksdjkasdjsdkffjdslakfsdfasdfasdsadfsdffasfsaf</div>
    <div class="date">
        <h4>sdfasdfsf</h4>
        fasdfsf<a href="#10"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link pull-right"></span></a></div>
  </li>
    <li id="11" class="list-group-item entries">
    <div class="name">
        <h3>jfklsdfjasklsjdlkasdjflkasfjkl</h3>
      </div>
    <div class="ids">
        <h4>fhdsjkafhsdkjfsdf</h4>
        fjasdklfjasdkfasd, jfkdl239fj23f2f, <a href="#">hjsdfkhfjksdfsdklfkaf</a>, fdjsklfsd</div>
    <div class="reason">
        <h4>fasdjkfasf</h4>
        fsdjklasdjl;fkfjalkfdjfkadfjajsdkfjsalksjadlfksadjlksdjkasdjsdkffjdslakfsdfasdfasdsadfsdffasfsaf</div>
    <div class="date">
        <h4>sdfasdfsf</h4>
        fasdfsf<a href="#11"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link pull-right"></span></a></div>
  </li>
    <li id="12" class="list-group-item entries">
    <div class="name">
        <h3>jfklsdfjasklsjdlkasdjflkasfjkl</h3>
      </div>
    <div class="ids">
        <h4>fhdsjkafhsdkjfsdf</h4>
        fjasdklfjasdkfasd, jfkdl239fj23f2f, <a href="#">hjsdfkhfjksdfsdklfkaf</a>, fdjsklfsd</div>
    <div class="reason">
        <h4>fasdjkfasf</h4>
        fsdjklasdjl;fkfjalkfdjfkadfjajsdkfjsalksjadlfksadjlksdjkasdjsdkffjdslakfsdfasdfasdsadfsdffasfsaf</div>
    <div class="date">
        <h4>sdfasdfsf</h4>
        fasdfsf<a href="#12"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link pull-right"></span></a></div>
  </li>
    <li id="13" class="list-group-item entries">
    <div class="name">
        <h3>jfklsdfjasklsjdlkasdjflkasfjkl</h3>
      </div>
    <div class="ids">
        <h4>fhdsjkafhsdkjfsdf</h4>
        fjasdklfjasdkfasd, jfkdl239fj23f2f, <a href="#">hjsdfkhfjksdfsdklfkaf</a>, fdjsklfsd</div>
    <div class="reason">
        <h4>fasdjkfasf</h4>
        fsdjklasdjl;fkfjalkfdjfkadfjajsdkfjsalksjadlfksadjlksdjkasdjsdkffjdslakfsdfasdfasdsadfsdffasfsaf</div>
    <div class="date">
        <h4>sdfasdfsf</h4>
        fasdfsf<a href="#13"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link pull-right"></span></a></div>
  </li>
    <li id="14" class="list-group-item entries">
    <div class="name">
        <h3>jfklsdfjasklsjdlkasdjflkasfjkl</h3>
      </div>
    <div class="ids">
        <h4>fhdsjkafhsdkjfsdf</h4>
        fjasdklfjasdkfasd, jfkdl239fj23f2f, <a href="#">hjsdfkhfjksdfsdklfkaf</a>, fdjsklfsd</div>
    <div class="reason">
        <h4>fasdjkfasf</h4>
        fsdjklasdjl;fkfjalkfdjfkadfjajsdkfjsalksjadlfksadjlksdjkasdjsdkffjdslakfsdfasdfasdsadfsdffasfsaf</div>
    <div class="date">
        <h4>sdfasdfsf</h4>
        fasdfsf<a href="#14"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link pull-right"></span></a></div>
  </li>
    <li id="15" class="list-group-item entries">
    <div class="name">
        <h3>jfklsdfjasklsjdlkasdjflkasfjkl</h3>
      </div>
    <div class="ids">
        <h4>fhdsjkafhsdkjfsdf</h4>
        fjasdklfjasdkfasd, jfkdl239fj23f2f, <a href="#">hjsdfkhfjksdfsdklfkaf</a>, fdjsklfsd</div>
    <div class="reason">
        <h4>fasdjkfasf</h4>
        fsdjklasdjl;fkfjalkfdjfkadfjajsdkfjsalksjadlfksadjlksdjkasdjsdkffjdslakfsdfasdfasdsadfsdffasfsaf</div>
    <div class="date">
        <h4>sdfasdfsf</h4>
        fasdfsf<a href="#15"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link pull-right"></span></a></div>
  </li>
    <li id="16" class="list-group-item entries">
    <div class="name">
        <h3>jfklsdfjasklsjdlkasdjflkasfjkl</h3>
      </div>
    <div class="ids">
        <h4>fhdsjkafhsdkjfsdf</h4>
        fjasdklfjasdkfasd, jfkdl239fj23f2f, <a href="#">hjsdfkhfjksdfsdklfkaf</a>, fdjsklfsd</div>
    <div class="reason">
        <h4>fasdjkfasf</h4>
        fsdjklasdjl;fkfjalkfdjfkadfjajsdkfjsalksjadlfksadjlksdjkasdjsdkffjdslakfsdfasdfasdsadfsdffasfsaf</div>
    <div class="date">
        <h4>sdfasdfsf</h4>
        fasdfsf<a href="#16"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link pull-right"></span></a></div>
  </li>
  </ul>
<ul class="pager">
    <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="pull-left text-muted">©</div>
    <div class="pull-right text-muted"><a href="#">#</a></div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: i think you should also explain what the problem was in above code-- @naila

Comment: @Naila Thank you, that is almost exactly what I want, however when viewing the page from a link (such as http://domain.com/index.html#4), the code doesn't get called and it is hidden like before, similar to what I ran into when trying to make a jquery fix of my own